# Should I change the battery of my Samsung A7 (2018)?

Tags: samsung, battery, battery-life

My phone shut off completely a few hours ago. It was at 20% and somehow it jumped to 0% and shut off. I didn't know what happened so I just put it to charge.

I had this phone for 2 years, if not 3. I've been using it everyday, nearly all day. For like 5-6 months I've been using it till it was at 20% percent and charge it till it was 90% ( I never used it till it was 0%). But in the first 2 years I used to let it charge overnight. I stopped doing this since July 2020( I think).

I tried my best to not use too much battery, I closed background apps, limited my brightness and leave it alone when it heated up( it started happening quite often for the last few months, but not that much).

It does charge normally.

I read an article about this kind of thing and what to do, and one of them was to do a factory reset. I don't want to do that.

Should I change the battery? I had this phone for like 3 years, I think I should change the battery.

Comment: The battery level is more an assumption not an exact value. That a device shuts down at 20% may happen if the assumptions on the remaining battery are not correct. Was it directly off or did the device properly performed a shutdown? Regarding the question if you should replace the battery the overall run time between two charges is more important. If that is enough from your perspective you can still use the current battery.

Comment: If you mean shut down by the 'power off' button, I didn't do that. The device on its own did that. And I did check, it was 20%. I just put the phone down and it shut off completely and when I tried to power it on, it showed me 0% and powered off again.

Comment: No I was asking if the phone was performing it's shut down sequence like a PC or if it was just off like a computer in a power outage. But if you have not seen the display when it happened you don't know which one happened. The problem is if it just goes off you lose data or some data may be written in a wrong way which can lead to problems. This is the reason I was asking.

Comment: There isn't any data lost, or written in the wrong way ( I don't think so). Everything is in its place, just how it was before. About the charging part, it does charge pretty good with one charger. But if I use a different one (similar to the first one) it charges very slow or not at all.

Comment: Assuming your battery is bad and therefore this power off scenarios happen more and more often, then with each power loss there is a small chance that something goes wrong. Therefore you should monitor your phone if this was a single event or if it happens frequently. If the latter happens it is time for a new battery.

Comment: So you're saying I should wait and see if it happens again?

Comment: professional repair service is recommended because there is high risk of breaking back cover https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p40OLb9_uAE

Answer (score 1):

Try other battery. If phone work properly than you can change battery.

Use code `*#*#4636#*#*`. go to battery information. If health is not good. Change the battery.

[image]

Comment: Have you or somebody else ever encountered a device with a battery state not "**Good**"?

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Comment: @Leyla Justo make it sure: you must enter this code in the phone app, on the numeric keypad, as if you were trying to call someone by entering their number manually. Also: charge your phone to full, then use it normally until the battery is empty and it turns off again. Do this once or twice (or 3 times). This will re-calibrate the charge monitor. If this helps, then the problem is solved.